# Prevent Protractor from spamming console — don't display resource requests?

Tags: protractor

When I run Protractor, it seems like I get terminal printouts of every single GET request it makes.

```
Test Suites & Specs:

1) App
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:12 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:12 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /polyfills.dll.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:12 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /vendor.dll.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:12 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /polyfills.bundle.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:12 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /vendor.bundle.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:12 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /main.bundle.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /0.chunk.js""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /1.chunk.js""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /assets/img/angularclass-avatar.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /5.chunk.js""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /6.chunk.js""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /assets/icon/favicon-16x16.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /assets/icon/favicon-96x96.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /assets/icon/favicon-32x32.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /assets/icon/android-icon-192x192.png" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
   √ should have a title
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
[Sun Apr 30 2017 18:43:13 GMT+0200 (Vest-Europa (sommertid))] "GET /polyfills.dll.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
...
```

How can I hide these?

I have added various Jasmine reporters, and would like to only see the results from them. As it is, all these resource requests make the console a mess.

Edit:

My `protractor.conf.js` (from [Angular 2 Webpack starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) with some irrelevant reporter additions)

```
require('ts-node/register');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

exports.config = {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',

  // use `npm run e2e`
  specs: [
    helpers.root('src/**/**.e2e.ts'),
    helpers.root('src/**/*.e2e.ts')
  ],
  exclude: [],

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showTiming: true,
    showColors: true,
    isVerbose: false,
    includeStackTrace: false,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  directConnect: true,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'args': ['show-fps-counter=true']
    }
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    const reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    const Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
    const JasmineConsoleReporter = require('jasmine-console-reporter');

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter('reports', true, true));

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new JasmineConsoleReporter({
        colors: 1,
        cleanStack: 1,
        verbosity: 4,
        listStyle: 'indent',
        activity: false
      })
    );

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
        savePath: 'target/screenshots',
        takeScreenshots: true,
        takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true
      })
    );

  },

   useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

Started from npm scripts

```
"e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
"server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
"protractor": "protractor",
```

Comment: What is your protractor config? How are you starting it?

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewEisenberg. See edit. I tried setting showTiming to false now, btw, didn't help.